How to create constraint in a scalable way?
I want to write this constraint:
A, B, and C are 1-bit wide
50% time all 3 are disabled.
10% time A enabled alone.
10% time B and C enabled together.
30% for all 3 enabled together

I only know how to do this with a bunch if/else conditions.  But, if I want this to be scalable, is there a better and more elegant way?

You need to explain how scalable needs to be implemented.

Use a dist.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 18.5.3 Distribution:
class d;
    rand bit a, b, c;
    constraint ccc {
        {a, b, c} dist {
            3'b000 := 50, // 50% time all 3 are disabled.
            3'b100 := 10, // 10% time A enabled alone.
            2'b011 := 10, // 10% time B and C enabled together.
            3'b111 := 30  // 30% for all 3 enabled together.
        };
    }
endclass

module tb;
    d d;
    initial begin
        d = new();
        repeat (1000) begin
            if (!d.randomize()) $fatal(2, "RAND FAIL");
            $display("result", , d.a, , d.b, , d.c);
        end
    end
endmodule

Prints on one simulator (grep result sim.log | sort | uniq -c):
507 result 0 0 0
103 result 0 1 1
105 result 1 0 0
285 result 1 1 1

